# Modules install successfully but cannot be found

Tags: perl, cpan, perlbrew, cpanm

I am wondering why I get "Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Module::Name' is not installed" even when dependency is has been installed. I am using `perlbrew` and `cpanm`. Here is an example of what happens with many modules that I try to install:

1. I try to install for example `URI::ws` as follow

> ```
> hamid@caspian:~$ /home/hamid/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm --installdeps URI::ws
> --> Working on URI::ws
> Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/URI-ws-0.03.tar.gz ... OK
> Configuring URI-ws-0.03 ... OK
> ==> Found dependencies: URI
> --> Working on URI
> Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.67.tar.gz ... OK
> Configuring URI-1.67 ... OK
> Building and testing URI-1.67 ... OK
> Successfully installed URI-1.67
> ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'URI' is not installed
> ! Bailing out the installation for URI-ws-0.03.
> 1 distribution installed
> ```

2. it tells me `URI` is not installed. So I install `URI` as follow:

> ```
> hamid@caspian:~$ /home/hamid/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm URI
> --> Working on URI
> Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.67.tar.gz ... OK
> Configuring URI-1.67 ... OK
> Building and testing URI-1.67 ... OK
> Successfully installed URI-1.67
> 1 distribution installed
> ```

3. I go back to what I originally wanted which was `URI::ws` and here is what I get:

> ```
> hamid@caspian:~$ /home/hamid/perl5/perlbrew/bin/cpanm URI::ws
> --> Working on URI::ws
> Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/URI-ws-0.03.tar.gz ... OK
> Configuring URI-ws-0.03 ... OK
> ==> Found dependencies: URI
> --> Working on URI
> Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/URI-1.67.tar.gz ... OK
> Configuring URI-1.67 ... OK
> Building and testing URI-1.67 ... OK
> Successfully installed URI-1.67
> ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'URI' is not installed
> ! Bailing out the installation for URI-ws-0.03.
> 1 distribution installed
> ```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do to stop it? If there is any more information that you need which I have missed please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Where was URI installed? From where did `cpanm` try to read it?

Comment: @choroba : hamid@caspian:~$ perl -MURI -e 'print $INC{"Time/HiRes.pm"}'
Can't locate URI.pm in @ INC

Comment: Your `cpanm` is installed at an odd location; is it running via the correct `perl`?

Comment: @friedo to make things work a bit more smoothly [perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl) can [install its own `cpanm`](http://www.perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html)  - so that is probably OK.  What can interfere with things is if you mix your own [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) and env vars like `$PERL5LIB` with perlbrew's environment (it is of course possible to use `local::lib` environments "inside" perlbrew with the `lib` command). @Hamster is URI installed for the version of perl your perlbrew is using? (*i.e.* are the files present in the perlbrew directory hierarchy).

Comment: @G.Cito I am using the latest version of Perl (5.20.2) and no, `find ~/perl5/perlbrew/ -name "*URI*"` gives me nothing

Comment: It looks like it is getting installed somewhere :-) Are all the right `PERLBREW_` env vars set? Anything like  `PERL_CPANM_OPT` ,`PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` or `PERL5LIB` present in your environment that might be mucking things up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019415/g-cito

> hamid@caspian:~$ PERL_MM_OPT=""; PERL_MB_OPT="";

has done the job :)

`local::lib` was messing stuff up. `URI.pm` was installed but not under the perlbrew directory.

Comment: If you have `local::lib` configured, you should check your `.bashrc` (or equivalent for your shell); `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT` are probably set there.

Comment: Added comments as an answer if you want to accept it :-) Be sure to heed @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's advice ++

Comment: This solution worked for me. Edit /root/.bashrc , set the variables to PERL_MM_OPT=""; PERL_MB_OPT=""; then reload bash with: source /root/.bashrc then reinstall modules

Answer (score 2):

With [perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl/) you can install a [perlbrew specific `cpanm`](http://www.perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html) which facilitates installing to the various `perls/` that are installed/managed using the perlbrew tool. I have found that this works very well.

However `perlbrew` *can* become confused if you mix in your own [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib)  and set related environment variables like `PERL5LIB`, `PERL_MM_OPT`, `PERL_MB_OPT` *etc.* (see for example the post by @cjm in [perlbrew and local::lib at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447595/perlbrew-and-locallib-at-the-same-time)).  Some of these environment vars can interact and interfere with perlbrew's own environment so it's generally best to avoid mixing them or simply to let perlbrew manage the environment using its own versions of those variables.

It is of course possible to use `local::lib` environments "inside" perlbrew with the lib command) and to do very complicated things for testing with different perl versions, shipping an application with requirements (*c.f.* [`Carton`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton)). In my own environment I was able to manage system perl;  a user installed `local::lib` that used the system perl; and a huge set of perlbrew perls all with judicious use of environment variables (thankfully a temporary set up while migrating between versions).

That sort of set up can get complicated very quickly, and is difficult to replicate. One of the greatest advantages of perlbrew is you can easily setup matching perl environments on multiple machines; or different perl environments on the same machine.